# List of Bedrock NBT workarounds to be posted as separate questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, minecraft, specific-question

Visit [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15245/250180) post to see my proposal on MCBE NBT question split.

Here is a list of the changes that should be done if we approve of it:

## New questions

If a question about BE NBT is possible using one of these, this should be its duplicate target. This includes all questions that would use NBT in Java Edition, even if the Bedrock Edition solution is different/doesn't involve commands.

- **How do I use commands to give myself a certain potion/tipped arrow from the Creative Inventory?** *If the asker wants to give themself (or another player) a potion or tipped arrow obtainable from the Creative Inventory.*
  **Answer:** Data values
- **How do I use `CanPlaceOn`/`CanDestroy` in Minecraft commands?**
  **Answer:** `{"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["stone"]}}`
- **How do I detect whether a player has an item in their inventory or in a specific slot?**
  **Answer:** New `hasitem=` selector argument.
- **How do I use commands to give a player an item with custom properties?**
  **Answer:** Load a structure containing the item entity on top of the player. [Details](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/374644/250180).
- **How do I summon a charged creeper?**
  **Answer:** Spawn event: `minecraft:become_charged`.
- **How do I summon a named mob?**
  **Answer:** `/summon chicken MrCluckCluck 1 2 3` or `/summon creeper 1 2 3 minecraft:become_charged MrBoomBoom`
- **How do I get a block with data to place myself?** *Applies to chests with items, signs with text, command blocks*
  **Answer:** Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + "pick block" on computer.<sup>(default middle mouse button)</sup>. Impossible using touch controls, but this should still be the duplicate target.
- **How do I set a block with data to a certain position?** *Applies to chests with items, signs with text, command blocks*
  **Answer:** Place block with data in template location. Use `/clone` to copy it to new position.
- **How do I summon a baby mob?**
  **Answer:** Use spawn event `minecraft:as_baby` for drowned/zombies and `minecraft:entity_born` for all other mobs.
- **How do I summon a villager with a certain profession?**
  **Answer:** Spawn events, see full list on [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn_event) and find villager ones.

## Existing questions

Use these questions as duplicate targets, not duplicate pointers.

- <del>[How can I obtain items that exceed their maximum enchantment level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290467/185203)</del> Nope, not doing that anymore because it can be solved with an NBT editor.

## Problems that can't be solved and should be duplicates of the [main question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

- **How do I give myself potions with custom effects?** *If the asker explicitly states that they want their own custom effects of the potion and not one available from the Creative Inventory*
- **How do I give myself an item with a custom lore?**
- **How do I give myself a skull with custom owner?**
- <s>**How do I detect items in a certain item slot?**</s> Now possible with new `hasitem=` selector argument.
- **How do I add attribute modifiers to items?**
- **How do I reference NBT in the `/clear` command?**

---

Express your approval/disapproval of these changes by upvoting/downvoting this post and upvoting/downvoting the original discussion visitable using the link at the top of my post. The proposed changes will be started on **August 12, 2020 at 00:00 UTC** if there is no direct opposition.

Suggestions for more items? Comment below.

Comment: "How do I use CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy in Minecraft commands?" should be one question for CanPlaceOn and one for CanDestroy, mirroring the Java edition situation. Otherwise, I agree with this proposal.

Comment: Morderators will need to be involved anyway, so I think doing anything before they get involved is premature. Another question to ask is who should post (and thus earn reputation from) the new questions. They shouldn't be community wiki since that would force all answers to be community wiki (although any answers copied from the original megathread by people other than the author should be community wiki, and should attribute the original author in the body)

Comment: Generally we'll give something a week or so to see if there's any direct opposition to a proposed change. Also, something you may not know - but mods can mark a question as a duplicate of more than one question. This is a possibility for questions that could go either way. @pppery (for the notification)

Comment: I did know that, and I'm pretty sure ExpertCoder14 did too, since they listed some questions twice in the community wiki list of duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

To help whoever implements this out, I am going to sort the existing duplicates between the new questions:

This is a community wiki answer, so feel free to edit it if there are mistakes or you want to add new questions.

---

## Change duplicate target to a new question— [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

These questions should have their duplicate target modified to a new question to be posted. These are grouped by the problem they are trying to solve.

#### [How do I give myself a potion with an effect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374591/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How to /give tipped arrows in Windows-10 edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/312172/185203)
- [How to give @p custom splash potion using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374244/185203)

#### [How do I use CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy in Minecraft commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374598/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Minecraft Bedrock Edition: Give lever that can only be placed on a specific block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/319328/185203)
- [NBT Syntax in MCPE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310411/185203)
- [How can I make a CanDestroy tool on Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/326198/185203)
- [How to use CanBreak and CanPlaceOn in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/353535/185203)
- [Placing and destroying blocks using Minecraft commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/360563/185203)
- [How do I create a sword that can only break cobwebs in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/355925/185203)
- [How do I use the 'can break' option using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363416/185203)
- [How can I /give myself a stone axe that can only break oak signs/planks in Adventure Mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368463/185203)
- [I'm having trouble making a tool that can break certain things in Minecraft Bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357209/185203)
- [How to make a pickaxe that can break only certain blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363870/185203)
- [Creating a tool that can break certain blocks as a command in Bedrock 1.14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/356278/185203)
- [Missing '}' in Minecraft Bedrock 'can_destroy' command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368380/185203)
- [Command Blocks with preset commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363765/185203) *Also listed in How do I get a block with data to place myself*
- [How do I make an unbreaking Diamond Pickaxe that can only break Obsidian in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334520/185203) *Also listed in How do I give myself an item with custom name/enchantments/other properties?*
- [What am I doing wrong with my /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346768/185203) *Also listed in "Keep these as duplicates of the main question" -> "Other"*

#### [How do I detect whether a player has an item in their inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371922/185203)— [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Player's inventory look for item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321896/185203)
- [How to detect a player holding a certain block in Minecraft Bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361708/185203)
- [Searching for a way in bedrock to test for a held item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370482/185203)

#### [How do I give myself an item with custom name/enchantments/other properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374643/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How do I make an unbreaking Diamond Pickaxe that can only break Obsidian in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334520/185203) *Also listed in "How do I use CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy in Minecraft commands"*
- [How do I /give myself a named pickaxe with unbreakable in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/337160/185203) *Also listed in "Keep these as duplicates of the main question" -> "Other"*
- [How to name an item using /give command in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/315934/185203)
- [Syntax Error when attempting to /give a player a named diamond sword?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/341101/185203)
- [Is there a way I can give players enchanted items and armor in MCPE with commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/312231/185203)
- [How to use MCPE /give command with add enchant attribute?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/303400/185203)
- [Can a player give an enchanted item on XBOX ONE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334378/185203)
- [/give an enchanted sword results in 'Component was not an object' error in Bedrock/Pocket Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/327258/185203)
- [How do I /give a named item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354108/185203)
- [How can I /give a player a named arrow in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/320651/185203)
- [How can I /give a named painting in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362335/185203)
- [How to use /give command to give enchanted items in Minecraft Bedrock (PS4)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/364352/185203)
- [I'm having trouble making a tool that can break certain things in Minecraft Bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357209/185203)
- [How can I rename items using /replaceitem in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/343663/185203)
- [How to use /give commands to create a written book in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock (iOS)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/367202/185203)
- [Why can't I /give a renamed 'paper' item in Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365163/185203)
- [Enchant a weapon using /give command in Minecraft Bedrock/PE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365785/185203)
- [How do I /give a Banner with a custom name in Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/349267/185203)

#### [How do I summon a charged creeper?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374608/28182)—[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> **Mod Note:** *no questions to mark duplicate here*

#### [How do I summon a named mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374587/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How do I give mobs custom names using command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/318245/185203)

#### [How do I get a block with data to place myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374589/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Command Blocks with preset commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363765/185203) *Also listed in How do I use CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy in Minecraft commands?*
- [Setting command block with preset commands in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/323981/185203)

#### [How do I set a block with data to a certain position?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374633/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How do I spawn a command block with a command in it on Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363101/185203)
- [How can I /setblock signs with text in MCPE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/338910/185203)
- [Using /setblock to get a command block with a command inside?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/347343/185203)

#### [How do I summon a baby mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374618/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How do I spawn a baby villager using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/344342/185203)

#### [How do I summon a villager with a certain profession?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374647/28182)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Is there a way to choose a villager's profession after spawning it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/369386/185203)

#### [How can I obtain items that exceed their maximum enchantment level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290467/185203)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [How can I get a sword with sharpness 1000?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363564/185203)
- [How to /give a player a named item with Level 10 enchants in Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/364107/185203)

---

## Keep these as duplicates of the main question

These questions should stay the way they are as duplicates of the [main question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition). They are grouped by the impossible problem that they are trying to workaround. Once again, do **NOT** create new questions for these, the headings for questions are just for readability.

**How do I give myself potions with custom effects?**

- [How to make a potion with the nausea and hunger effect, and be named “Rum” using Command block in MCPE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/324133/185203)

**How do I give myself an item with a lore on it?**

**How do I get or `/setblock` a skull with a custom owner?**

- [What happened to the "give skull" command in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/339472/185203)
- [Is it possible to get custom heads in Minecraft Bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/356295/185203)
- [Minecraft * Line 1, Column 2 Missing ‘}’ or object member name error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354863/185203)
- [/give @p skull is not working](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321760/185203)
- [Getting Player Heads MCPE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354741/185203)
- [how to get player heads on xbox one 1.14.6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371208/185203)
- [Why can't I get player heads in Minecraft on the Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368219/185203)

**How do I detect items in a certain item slot?**

- [How to detect a item in mainhand on MCPE using command block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/312728/185203)
- [How can I use /testfor to see if someone is holding a diamond in their main hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/336362/185203)
- [Is there anyway to use the setblock command to when I hold an item in my hand (torch) it places a torch on the ground (bedrock edition)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361993/185203)

**How do I add attribute modifiers to items?**

- [Using Attribute modifiers to add armour to Elytra (MCBE)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354316/185203)
- [Trying to do over 1000000 damage in a sword but a comma is in the way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/349048/185203)

**How do I reference NBT in the `/clear` command?**

- [Using /clear to clear an item with a custom name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362821/185203)

**Other**

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [What am I doing wrong with my /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346768/185203) *Also listed under "Change duplicate target to a new question" -> "How do I use CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy in Minecraft commands"*
- [How do I /give myself a named pickaxe with unbreakable in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/337160/185203) *Also listed in "Change duplicate target to a new question" -> "How do I use commands to give a player an item with custom name/enchantments/other properties?"*
- [How can I shorten the time until a TNT explosion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362818/185203)
- [How do I get a map with specific X and Z centers in the Bedrock Engine?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/319384/185203)
- [Is it possible to use /summon a tipped arrow in bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368142/185203) *note: this is summoning an arrow entity, not giving a player an arrow*
- [Why can’t I summon invisible item frames in Minecraft PE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/372244/185203)
- [How could I detect with command blocks when a mob is at a certain health or percentage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365370/185203)
- [Referencing JSON file in Minecraft Bedrock via command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/372760/185203)
- [How do I spawn a zombie with the closest player's name MCPE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/358801/185203)
- [Is it impossible to add certain NBT tags to commands in PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357174/185203)
- [How do I customize how fast a horse is going with commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361133/185203)
- [In Minecraft Bedrock Edition, how would I specify larger, zoomed- out maps in a /clear command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363561/185203)
- [Having trouble making (MCPE) items unbreakable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365401/185203)

## Reopen these questions entirely — [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Everytime I do the CanPlaceOn command it says i'm wrong](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368408/185203) *The actual problem with this command is that they got the block ID wrong, which has nothing to do with the general syntax issues*
- [Why won't "falling_block" work in minecraft bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365685/185203) *There is actually a much bigger problem, and that is the fact that `falling_block` is not supported in `/summon`. This huge problem means NBT is irrelevant to the situation.*
- [How to tell if a certain item is in a player inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371922/185203) *This question should probably be re-opened and become the canonical for this workaround, since cherryblossom posted an answer to it*

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since we've proposed this, and I don't see any direct opposition to this, so I believe we can start now. We will be working through three phases of this upgrade:

## Phase 1: New Question Creation—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As suggesters of this proposal, [I](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/250180/expertcoder14), [pppery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/185203/pppery), and [cherryblossom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/188492/cherryblossom) will be posting separate questions for each workaround. We will be splitting the questions among each other as equally as possible. (They cannot be community wiki because that would force all the answers to be community wiki.)

Here is the split and the work needed to be done by each user. These were chosen randomly by a random number generator:

### pppery's questions

- How do I use commands to give myself a certain potion/tipped arrow from the Creative Inventory?
- How do I summon a villager with a certain profession?
- How do I summon a baby mob?

### cherryblossom's questions

- How do I get a block with data to place myself?
- How do I use `CanPlaceOn`/`CanDestroy` in Minecraft commands?
- How do I summon a charged creeper?

### ExpertCoder14's questions

- How do I summon a named mob?
- How do I give myself an item with custom name/enchantments/other properties?
- How do I set a block with data to a certain position?

If you are one of the users with a question assigned, please look at the main post above for its answer. You may then add a new question to the network. Ensure your question has a notice at the top detailing why it's being posted and link it to the [original proposal](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15245/250180) and the [main BE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180). This way, users won't mistake it as being another duplicate of the old duplicate target. (We'll remove these notices after the movement is complete.)

Here is an example notice:

> *This question has been posted as part of the Minecraft Bedrock NBT question split and will become a duplicate target for related questions instead of the [main BE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180). Discuss the proposal [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15245/250180).*

## Phase 2: Duplicate Retargeting—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks to the great effort of [pppery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/185203/pppery), a list has been compiled with all the duplicates of the Minecraft BE NBT question. After, and only after, phase 1 is complete, we can begin retargeting duplicates to their questions.

In the big list post, you'll find one section for duplicate retargeting at the top. A [moderator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) can then reroute the duplicates to one of the new questions.

To be clear, for all the questions who need duplicate retargeting, the [main BE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180) should ***NOT*** be kept on the list of duplicates. It will be reserved for the questions that ask for something impossible only.

## Phase 3: Reorganization of the [main BE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)—[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For this last phase, we will be cleaning up the [main BE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180). pppery had suggested this.

1. The accepted answer by cherryblossom can be changed to reflect the changes to this duplicate retargeting. Adding a notice like *"If you've been sent here by a close notice, this means your problem is not solvable."*, adding a list of the impossible problems (see question post above) and linking to each workaround would be greatly appreciated.
2. All answers can be deleted except for the accepted answer. *This step has caused some controversy from the community, and it is not clear whether we will be doing it. I'm just posting it here for the record.*

Answer (score 1):

## Actions I would suggest other than retargeting duplicates

1. Delete all answers to the [main question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/185203) except for the accepted answer (no content is actually lost here, since the information will be contained in the new questions, and no significant reputation will be lost, since all but one of them are more than 2 months old and have a score of greater than two)
2. Edit the remaining answer to delete the bit about `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` (again, now a separate question), and include a link to each of the workaround questions, in case someone whose question is actually possible ends up there by mistake.
3. Lock the question with a "wiki answer" lock to prevent any additional workarounds from being posted there as answers as opposed to additional self-answered questions. This includes making the answer community wiki.

> ## Note
>
> This post has caused some controversy in the comments below. If you would like to argue this case, please make your argument on the [discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15622/250180) that stemmed off of this post.

Comment: For convenience, we should also put a list of impossible scenarios before the list of workarounds, or a message on the answer/question saying "If your question has been closed as a duplicate of this, this means your problem can't be solved." This way users reaching the question won't think that they have to browse all the workarounds, and that they immediately know that it isn't possible.

Comment: Agree. Either way, the answer to that question becomes community wiki, so the precise wording can be decided later.

Comment: Some notes here: answers should not be forcibly deleted simply because content is being copied out of them. The fact that reputation points will be preserved does not justify doing so. Those answers' authors are of course free to delete their own answers. In addition, the question should not be locked simply as a matter of convenience, and even if it should be, setting the answer to "community wiki" would not accomplish that, and even if it did, that setting should be used very sparingly if at all and I think you need to make a stronger argument for using it here.

Comment: I see now that three of the four existing answers on that main question are owned by users who are involved in this project, Each of those users can delete their own answers. For the other answer, you can do your best to convince that user that they should delete it. If you can't, you will just have to live with it.

Comment: You don't have the right to delete someone else's answer with the justification presented here. Your desire to clean up the post does not override that user's right to post their answer on the question. In other words, there are exactly two possible outcomes here: either the user deletes their own answer, and it goes away, or they do not delete it, and it stays.