# Should we deliver the final blow of the Bedrock NBT question split?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

It's been a while, but I'd like to revisit the movement we made of splitting the [MCBE NBT question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102) into multiple questions for each possible workaround. We made a [plan](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15269/250180) for retargeting duplicates, followed it, and now the question directory is much more organized.

The thing I want to bring up is the final step of phase 3:

> All answers can be deleted except for the accepted answer. *This step has caused some controversy from the community, and it is not clear whether we will be doing it. I'm just posting it here for the record.*

That step was from a comment discussion from [pppery](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/185203), who, in the early planning stages of this movement, had a final step in mind for completing the movement. I believe, remembering before that comment discussion was deleted, that it wanted the following to occur:

- Delete [villager1's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/357712/250180) on the main BE NBT question.
- Lock the question with a wiki answer lock to prevent new answers from being added.
- Convert the main accepted answer (or maybe the entire question) into a community wiki question/answer.

We never actually discussed this part of the movement because after we completed step 1 of phase 3, the whole movement seemed to become inert. No more progress.

So, just so that we don't leave any loose ends untied, I would like to deliver this final discussion starter to the community.

**Do we deliver the final blow?** or **Leave things the way they are?**

Visit the original proposal [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15249/250180), but please make your arguments on this question, rather than continuing the discussion in the comments there.

## Arguments that support it

- [villager1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/229353)'s answer should be deleted because the info contained in the answers is already present in the separate workarounds.
- It will make the BE NBT question more organized and focus more on content than users.
- It will stop users from adding unnecessary answers and tell them to post on a workaround-specific question.
- By making the answer (and possibly the question) community wiki, it will encourage users to add their own workarounds directly instead of asking a higher-level user to check it. Time saver!

## Arguments that oppose it

- It is unfair to [villager1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/229353) because they worked hard to make their answer and it should not be deleted without permission.
- It is too minor a change to be worth it.
- The answer (or question) should not be made community wiki because new NBT workarounds should be double-checked by higher-level users before being added to the official list.

Feel free to contribute your additional arguments or support some of these ones in your answer below.

---

**Edit**: It's been a while, and there hasn't been any direct opposition to this. Does that mean we can go ahead?

Comment: You understand what I proposed correctly. I should probably undelete that answer now, given that the main reason I deleted it was annoyance at getting repeated pings from the discussion that was taking place in the comments.

Comment: Also note that villager1 wouldn't lose reputation because [the post has a score of 3 or higher and has been visible on the site for more than 60 days](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

Comment: @pppery I would encourage you to do that so I can reference it in this question. That would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: OK, done, it's [this answer](/a/15249)

Comment: @pppery Great! I added a notice on the post just so that the comment discussion won't continue.

Comment: [This](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/list-of-bedrock-nbt-workarounds-to-be-posted-as-separate-questions/15249#15249) Can solve your problem.
(Since this is a link from stack overflow it doesn't go away) (Thanks to ppery for comment, I answered for googlers who wants to solve problem faster)