# Reopen commands randomness question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, minecraft, reopen

I've just stumbled upon the many ways of random output generation, mostly on [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18133/250180) asking for a solution involving redstone, and [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229610/250180) asking for a solution involving commands. The one involving commands is closed as a pointer to the one about redstone.

**Why?**

Scrolling down on the redstone random question, you'll find [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376944/250180), which is a neat combination of all ways to get random generation in Minecraft. The fact that the answer is there signals me that something is off here. Because that answer hasn't gained enough traction with the community, I'm raising it here. I'll quote the part of the answer that sums the situation up perfectly:

> ### This question is a duplicate magnet
>
> This question appears to be the main attractor for any and all questions involving creating a source of randomness in Minecraft. But, most of the solutions are still in the duplicates or even in other related questions.
>
> ### This is a meta-answer post.
>
> I'm compiling together the answers to the question in a single place to provide a more complete answer to the problem. This question is duplicated a bunch of times, and the good (partial) answers are strewn about the site. See below for the detailed explanation as to why a meta-answer is valuable; in short: randomness is hard.
>
> ### This post could potentially be moderated
>
> Although I'm unsure as to why and where what should go, due to how much entropy has accumulated. Perhaps the additions could be merged as edits, but they do substantially change the content of (some of the posts) by adding a lot of omitted information, so would not qualify as standard edits. For example, some of the answers link to videos or other answers as "examples", but then those videos sometimes use a completely different hack with different caveats as a result.
>
> Or maybe it should be a meta post linked to the question; or maybe its own separate question, i.e.; what are the caveats to the solutions of {canon question}?
>
> ### This post is very likely incomplete
>
> I've collected a large number of solutions located in other questions and answers, but likely not everything: there's probably more duplicates. Feel free to edit this post with any answers that provide more insights or alternative methods.
>
> ### Finally...
>
> With the explanations out of the way: Let's list the other solutions to the question, and why and how they are applicable.
>
> There's also some commentary in the list which is important to any implementer, any caveats to the solutions not already provided in the answers themselves.

We've had a [similar problem](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15245/250180) of question posts becoming too much of a hub than they were built to be. We fixed this by splitting the question into smaller problems that each had their own solution.

I feel like the redstone randomness post is going down the same road. But I think we don't need to go as far as splitting the posts, simply just reopen the commands one. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that questions about implementing randomness using Redstone circuits would be different to (and require different answers/outcomes to) questions about implementing randomness in Minecraft commands, so I have reopened the question.

I have also edited a note into the questions, explaining why each is different to the other one:

- [How can I randomise the output of a redstone circuit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18133/28182)
- [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229610/28182)

Comment: That's great to hear. Thanks for your work!